# cant see my list items

Tags: android, listview, actionbarsherlock

I am getting an empty list on the view, dont have any errors but just get list empry while my array isn't empty.

my xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLa"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"   
      android:id="@+id/mainListView"/>  

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconremove"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
         android:src="@drawable/removeicon"
         android:visibility="gone"
          />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="20dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

my adapter

```
public class ListRssAdpter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private int id;
    private List<String> items;
    public ListRssAdpter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<String> list) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, list);
        mContext = context;
        id = textViewResourceId;
        items = list;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
        View mView = v;
        if (mView == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            mView = vi.inflate(id, null);
        }
        TextView tx = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        //if this view is on main screen
        if (tx == null) {
            tx = ((TextView) mView);
        }
        tx.setText(items.get(position));
        return mView;

    }
}
```

and the main code:

```
        ListView    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainListView ); 

        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        DBAdapter dbAdpter=new DBAdapter(this);
        ListRssLinkAndTitle=(ArrayList)dbAdpter.getWantedItemsList(this,"link","RssTitle","Rtl");//get wanted items from db 
        ArrayList<String> listKeys=new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int j=0;j<ListRssLinkAndTitle.size();j++)
            listKeys.add(ListRssLinkAndTitle.get(j).title);
        ListRssAdpter   listAdapter = new ListRssAdpter(this, R.layout.titlesrss, listKeys);


        if (ListRssLinkAndTitle.isEmpty())
            Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(),  getResources().getString(R.string.emtyRssList),0).show();
        lv.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Tanks for helping

Comment: Can you post the full code of the adapter?

Comment: Where is `items` declared and filled?

Comment: Is `R.layout.titlesrss` the layout file from the question?

Comment: are you sure that you are not getting the toast (guessing if its empty). Once check if the items.get(position) is giving some value like printing it in a log and checking it

Comment: I just did    tx.setText("sdfsd"); and still get nothing.maybe something wrong with my xml?  or on my main SherlockActivity

Comment: am not sure but once give the android:layout_height fill parent to the main linear layout and check it

Comment: Luksprog ,yes the layout is R.layout.titlesrss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few potential problems:

1. Your LinearLayout has a horizontal orientation and the ListView is as wide as the screen. So you will never see the ImageView or TextView. The easiest solution is to set the LinearLayout's orientation to vertical:

   ```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/linearLa"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical" >
   ```

   But you have also set the ListView's parameters to fill the screen, so you still won't see anything else... Again the easy solution is to place the smaller items above the ListView.
2. This logic should work:

   ```
   TextView tx = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
   //if this view is on main screen
   if (tx == null) {
       tx = ((TextView) mView);
   }
   ```

   But if you are making a custom adapter, you should already know what your layout is and don't need have the if clause since `tx` should never be `null`.
3. You have set your toast to display for 0 seconds... Try using a standardized time frame:

   ```
   Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.emtyRssList), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   ```

---

**Addition**

> yes the layout is R.layout.titlesrss

If the XML above is your row layout, then you are createing a ListView inside each row of your main ListView... Your row layout should be something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLa"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconremove"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
         android:src="@drawable/removeicon"
         android:visibility="gone"
          />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="20dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! the first step just did all!

Comment: Glad I could help! You should watch [this lesson](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/TurboChargeUiAndroidFast.html) from Android's programmers for tips and tricks to help speed up your code.

Comment: but what about 
    <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
      android:id="@+id/mainListView"/>

Comment: Your ListView should only be in your Activity's layout that you pass to `setContentView()`, your row layout should never have a ListView.